# How create linear regression model for multi dimensional data in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have read a guide start for tensorflow here's [a link](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started)
In this guide use an example of one dimension for model y = W*x +b.
After that i tried create 2 dimensional for x . Follow is my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random as rd
rd.seed(2)

#model is 2*x1 + x2 - 3 = y
def create_data_train():
x_train = np.asarray([[2,3],[6,7],[1,5],[4,6],[10,-1],[0,0],[5,6],
[8,9],[4.5,6.2],[1,1],[0.3,0.2]])
w_train = np.asarray([[2,1]])
b = np.asarray([[-3]])
y_train = np.dot(x_train, w_train.T) + b
for i in range(y_train.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y_train.shape[1]):
        y_train[i][j] += 1-rd.randint(0,2)
return x_train,y_train

# step 1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
# step 2
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.subtract(y,y_),2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
#step 3
x1,y1 = create_data_train()
x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x1)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y1)
print(x_train)
print(y_train)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(x_train))
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:x_train,y_:y_train})

endW ,endb = sess.run([W,b])
print(endW)
print(endb)
```

But when i run, i encounter an error is :

> TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here because you cannot feed a tensor to **feed_dict**.

Since you have following two lines,

```
x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x1)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y1)
```

You are converting **x1** and **y1** to tensors (*i.e* your input and outputs). Feed **x1** and **y1** directly without converting to tensors.

Hope this helps.